# Is there a good Terraform provider for provisioning VMs on KVM/QEMU

Tags: linux, configuration-management

I am currently using virt-install to create new VMs on KVM/QEMU and then using Terraform to configure software on them. I want to combine these steps and use a Terraform provider to automate VM creation but then be able to tear the whole system down with a single command. Can anyone suggest a suitable Terraform provider to achieve this?

I am currently using matchbox with dnsmasq to PXE boot my VMs so all my solution needs to do is create a VM using Terraform with the necessary flags, for example:

```
virt-install --name "test" --network=bridge=bridge0,mac=FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF --boot=hd,network --memory=1024 --vcpus=2 --pxe --disk pool=default,size=10 --os-type=linux --os-variant=generic --noautoconsole --events on_poweroff=preserve
```

and be able to simply run `terraform destroy` to undo everything

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best KVM provider I've found so far is [terraform-provider-libvirt](https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt). It provides full support for managing KVM VMs from Terraform and it still under very active development.

The only minor downside is that binaries are currently only available for openSUSE - other platforms require you to compile from source (like Terraform it's written in Go).

Comment: Now terraform-provider-libvirt release binary builds for Centos 7, Fedora 28, Ubuntu 18.04 and Open SUSE
https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt/releases

Comment: I don't think that module provides pure automated `--pxe` boot. Yes, you can pass ignition files directly, putting under the question - do you need Matchbox at all, but... personally i also want to pass `mac` address and `--pxe` argument so VM could boot and grab ignition on its own without forcing Terraform to deal with those configs. In my case i have dedicated "bootstrap" server which is set up by Ansible and has DHCP, DNS, Matchbox, TFTP and iPXE. So basically, if i run the same command as author provided, my VMs runs and configures automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There are now packages for CentOS, Fedora and Ubuntu as well:

https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=systemsmanagement:terraform&package=terraform-provider-libvirt

Comment: terraform-provider-libvirt rpm built for CentOS7 but it depend on not existing for CentOS7 rerraform package

Comment: Careful:  after so long, the maintainer of this thing on OBS got bored of supporting EL7 and it's now gone.  Great news!  The SRPM for Fedora may still build.  Take it to copr and see if it'll build for you.  https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/systemsmanagement:/terraform/Fedora_32/src/terraform-provider-libvirt-0.6.2+git.1590253051.d1cf93cd-1.1.src.rpm

Also, https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/harbottle/main/epel-7-x86_64/ has your repo for terraform and a trove of other great tools.